# Media query is working fine when I change size while developer tools pane. But when I change browser size by restoring down it doesn't work

Tags: css, media-queries

When I put change the size using developer panel, by changing the size, it works fine, but if I decrease the size of browser directly there is no effect seen. Even when I make my dimension responsive from toggle device toolbar and then change it, it doesn't work at all.

I have just started learning css, this is simple code from w3school. kindly help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
<p>The media query will only apply if the media type is screen and the viewport is 480px wide or wider.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the image dimension responsive, media query doesn't work at all

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The example in your question works fine for me. What does the _Elements_ dev-tools panel say about the currently applied styles?

Comment: @phil I don't see anything over elements, when I change the screen size using elements pane by increasing  or decreasing size it works perfectly, otherwise it doesn't. Even responsive dimension doesn't work.

Comment: I meant that you should get it into a state where it's showing the wrong thing then use the _Elements_ panel to inspect the body styles. There might be something else overriding your media query

Comment: It works perfectly you have to size your browser to a width of 480px or less. Try it in a new window.

Comment: @ruleboy21 you can see from OP's screenshot that they have the width at 286px. It should be pink

Comment: @Phil yes I see that. That is opened in the dev-tools so it's easy to resize it. But when the dev-tools is closed, its a bit difficult especially if a lot of tabs are opened. That's why I said he should open it in a new window. It's easy to shrink the browser that way.

Comment: I did resize it in new window. After adjusting the size, all I am seeing is this  https://ibb.co/4KKzQ7C. Sorry i am very to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need a meta tag in the head. e.g

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Your code (without this) works as a SO snippet because in that case it's run in an iframe within a document which already has a meta tag at the top.

```
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: pink;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
      body {
        background-color: white;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
  <p>The media query will only apply if the media type is screen and the viewport is 480px wide or wider.</p>
  <script>
    function getWidth() {
      alert('Viewport width = ' + window.getComputedStyle(document.body).width);
    }
    window.onresize = getWidth;
  </script>
</body>
```

Running this with the browser dev tools inspect facility gives, for example:

[image]

Take out the meta tag and you will see the vewport width is reported as the width of that area in the browser (980px in my test on Edge Windows10).

Comment: I added the snippet in OP's question but you're spot on with the diagnosis. I've restored the original markup since it shows the full document

Comment: @phil - yes that's the problem with snippet type systems - they change the experiment 's environment :)